# Get WeekDay Name from WeekDay integer in SQL Server 2012

Tags: datetime, sql-server-2012

How can I get the week day name knowing the week day integer value using only T-SQL and without using CASE statement?

For example, if week day integer value is 2, then I need to get 'Monday' as week day name.

```
declare @currentDate as DATETIME;
set @currentDate = getdate();
SELECT DATEPART(dw, @currentDate) as WeekDayIntegerValue,
       '' as WeekDayName --i need the t-sql to use for this column
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use DATENAME for this. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174395.aspx

```
declare @currentDate as DATETIME;
set @currentDate = getdate();
SELECT DATEPART(dw, @currentDate) as WeekDayIntegerValue,
       DATENAME(weekday, @currentDate) as WeekDayName 
       --i need the t-sql to use for this column
```

Also, you should get out of the habit of not using the shortcuts to the date functions.

- [Bad Habits to Kick : Using shorthand with date/time operations](https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations)

Comment: You mean use 'weekday' in place of 'dw', when you say to avoid shortcuts?