# Convert weekday name from weekday integer in T-SQL

Tags: t-sql

*[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29703577) did not answer my question, which is...*

I have the day of the week (weekday) as an integer (where 1=Sun, 2=Mon, etc.), and I want to get the *name* of the weekday (e.g., `'Mon'` or `'Monday'`) corresponding to it.

I know I can use a `case` expression, like this:

```
case @wkday  --int
    when 1  then 'Sun'
    when 2  then 'Mon'
    when 3  then 'Tue'
    when 4  then 'Wed'
    when 5  then 'Thu'
    when 6  then 'Fri'
    when 7  then 'Sat'
end;
```

But this is more cumbersome than using a built-in function.

I know I can also convert the integer into a date and then extract the weekday name from it, like this:

```
dateName(weekday, dateFromParts(1978, 1, @wkday))    -- 1978-01-01 is a Sun
```

But this seems like a lot of wasted effort, having to convert to a date and then do date calculations, all just to convert an integer into a string.

So what is the built-in function I'm looking for?

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
 Select DATENAME(weekday, YourDateColumn)
 From table
```

The DATENAME() function returns the date part as a character string whereas the DATEPART() returns the date part as an integer.

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes

Comment: I still need to extract only the first three chars of the value returned by `datename()`, e.g., to convert `'Tuesday'` into `'Tue'`.

Comment: Select Format(DATENAME(weekday, YourDateColumn),'ddd')
 From table

Answer (score 0):

```
Select DATENAME(weekday, YourDateColumn)
From table
```

Or
SELECT
, [Date]
, FORMAT([Date],'MMM') AS [Short Month Name]
, FORMAT([Date],'ddd') AS [Short Weekday Name]
FROM table